# Stop propagation of event from child to parent and inbetween ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry the title maybe a bit bogus. but here its, imagine I have 3 divs like this :

```
<div id="1" class="clickable">
    <div id="2" class="some random thing">
        <div id="3" class="clickable">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

now imagine I have

`$('.clickable').on('click',function(){blahblah});`

I want them both to be clickable but not at the same time.
When I click the inside clickable class div (where the id is 3) both the the inner one and the parent  one will trigger the blahblah. I know I can use something like

`$('.clickable').on('click',function(e){e.stopPropagation(); blahblah});`

but the problem is even if I do that, clicking the middle child (the one with the id of 2) will trigger the blah blah on the parent as well.

Is there anyway to stop that? For example if this div and only this div not parent not child, only this div has the class of clickable, be clickable.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

event.stopPropogation stops the event from bubbling up the event chain, but this conflicts when you click on the middle div. I am posting the javascript code that you can refer to. Inside the click event listener, the conditional if block checks whether the event was triggered in that particular div element, hence stopping the event bubbling.

```
document.getElementById("outer").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target !== this) {
        return;
    }
    alert("You clicked outer div!");

});
document.getElementById("middle").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target !== this) {
        return;
    }
    alert("You clicked middle div!");

});
document.getElementById("inner").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    alert("You clicked inner div!");

});
```

You can also refer to this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9fskuunr/3/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something like this

```
$(".clickable").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    var id = $(e.target).attr('id');
    alert(id + ' is clicked');
}).children(':not(.clickable)').click(function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

See the JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/3h4yvfv4/1/

Answer (score 0):

One approach you might want to consider is to use event delegation. That way you only assign one event handler, rather than multiple event handlers for every `.clickable` element, which may give you a performance benefit depending on how many .clickable elements you have on a given page.

The code using event delegation looks something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target),
        isClickable,
        closestClickable,
        isNestedInClickable;

    isClickable = target.hasClass('clickable');
    if (isClickable) {
        handleClick(e);
    } else {
        closestClickable = target.closest('.clickable');
        isNestedInClickable = !!closestClickable;
    }

    if (isClickable || isNestedInClickable) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});

function handleClick(e) {
    console.log(e.target.id + ' clicked');
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sytkvgng/2/